# Two definitions of Riemann-Stieltjes integral (Apostol's "Mathematical Analysis")

Tags: analysis

In Apostol's *Mathematical Analysis*, Chap.7, there are two definitions of Riemann-Stieltjes integral:  
**Definition 1** Let $P$ =$\left \{ x_0,x_1,\cdots ,x_n \right \}$ be a partition of $\left [ a,b \right ]$ and let $t_k$ be a point in the subinterval $\left [ x_{k-1},x_k \right ]$. A sum of the form
$$S\left ( P,f,\alpha  \right )= \sum_{k=1 }^{n}f\left (t_k  \right ) \Delta \alpha _k$$
is called a Riemann-Stieltjes sum of $f$ with respect to $\alpha$. We say $f$ is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to $\alpha$ on $\left [  a,b\right ] $, and we write "$f\in R\left ( \alpha  \right ) $ on $\left [ a,b \right ] $" if there exists a number $A$ having the following property:For every $\varepsilon >0$, there exists a partition $P_\varepsilon$ of $\left [ a,b \right ]$ such that for every partition $P$ finer than $P_\varepsilon$ and for every choice of the points $t_k$ in $\left [ x_{k-1},x_k \right ] $, we have \left | S\left ( P,f,\alpha  \right )  -A\right  | <\varepsilon.
**Definition 2** $f$ is integrable with respect to \alpha if there exists a real number A having the property that for every \varepsilon >0, there exists a $\delta  >0$ such that for every partition $P$ of $\left [  a,b\right ] $ with norm $\left \| P \right \| < \delta$ and for every choice of $t_k$ in $\left [ x_{k-1},x_k \right ] $,we have $\left | S\left ( P,f,\alpha  \right )  -A\right  | <\varepsilon $.
These two definitions are not even equivalent. And I don't understand why.